# Is Graphics tablet better than mouse for precise movements in terms of hand and wrist tiredness?

Tags: mouse, graphics-tablet, rsi

I usually do works which require precise cursor movement. For example I need to move the cursor to a specific pixel on the screen precisely. However since I need to grab the mouse with my entire hand, this activity makes my hand and wrist uncomfortable very fast.

I think this kind of activity can be more easily achieved by grabbing a pen so I'm eyeing on graphics tablet. However every review I've found so far on Internet doesn't mention about it, none of my acquaintances have any, so I'm not sure if graphics tablet is suitable for this particular activity.

Which device is more suitable for the precise cursor movement in terms of hand and wrist tiredness?
(Using keyboard helps, but it is not an option for me so please don't mention about it)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is more natural to use a pressure sensitive pen on a graphic tablet than it is to use a mouse.

If you analyze the process, a mouse often uses the whole arm and if done improperly, involves the upper arm in an activity that wasn't in the original design spec, leading to repetitive stress injury in the whole arm.

A pen uses more natural finger and wrist movements and I've found it to be a lot easier for precise control.